# How to get electromagnetic field tensor of photon gas?

Tags: electromagnetism, photons, equilibrium

Momentum spectrum of ideal photon gas depends on its temperature.But sometimes I need these thermal photons to act like 'electromagnetic field'.I want to take them into charged particles' motion equation instead of calculation of scattering,which is used by kinetic equation.

So how to get electromagnetic field expression of photon gas or how to put thermal photons into motion equation of charged particles?